# как включить комментарии или отзывы на конкретной статье в wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Вот, собственно вопрос...почему у меня на сайте под WordPress в некоторых статьях есть форма комментариев, а в некоторых этой формы нет, не смотря на то, что во вкладке "настройка экрана" в редактировании статьи галочка на комментариях стоит.
На деле вместо формы комментариев висит надпись "Отзывы недоступны!"

```
    <?php if ( ! comments_open() & is_single() )  : ?><p><?php _e( 'Отзывы недоступны!', 'onsen' ); ?></p><?php endif; ?>
```

кусок кода комментировался, в надежде, что вместо этой формы у меня всплывет форма комментариев, но, увы, пропала всего-лишь надпись...значит, копать нужно где-то глубже...в целом, суть вопроса такова: Какие условия нужно соблюсти, чтобы форма комментариев гарантированно присутствовала в статье(всего одна из кучи статей висит с этой надписью...)

Answer (score 1):

В админ-части сайта можно установить разрешение/запрет на комментирование отдельной записи. См. картинку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Галочки "во вкладке "настройка экрана" в редактировании статьи" мало, надо еще и внизу галочку поставить.

Comment: проблема в том, что у меня нет галочки обсуждения именно в этой статье. во всех остальных она есть! как мне быть-ума не приложу. статьи все шаблонные, значит одинаково построены...а тут-такой трабл, что даже и не знаю куда копать...

Comment: Отключайте плагины по одному, смените тему на стандартную. Так сузите круг поисков.

Comment: Advanced Custom Fields PRO отключал этот плагин-пропадали комментарии, и помимо комментариев еще куча плюшек(сайт мне перешел сегодня, так сказать, принял эстафету)

Comment: Посредством временного отключения плагинов надо понять, когда ПОЯВИТСЯ возможность комментировать.

Comment: Отключил все плагины кроме Custom Pust type UI(при его отключении вообще не отображается блок с постом.), результата нуль. грешить на Custom Post Type UI?

Comment: Что значит, не отображается блок с постом? Какой такой блок? Покажите. Редактирование записей - штатный функционал WP

Comment: https://prntscr.com/gchppz
https://prntscr.com/gchq6e
вот, собсна, и пример.

Comment: нет, как в админке это выглядит?

Comment: немного не понял вопроса(к слову,все записи нужные пропали и в админке(они не отображаются))

Comment: Я вам привел картинку со стандартным функционалом WP. Когда пропали записи? При отключении какого плагина? Покажите картинку в админке с проблемой.

Comment: проблема в том, что при отключении плагина из админ панели пропадает запись , в которой находятся статьи https://prnt.sc/gcit36
на месте прочерка слева должна находиться запись "производители", которая, собственно и добавлена с помощью плагина Custom Post Type UI, на сколько я понимаю